# jQuery Ajax for three drop down

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i have three dropdown,
The first one populating value from database, Second and third will get their values by ajax call.

And the problem is at first loading of the page when i'm selecting the first dropdown the second dropdown change from please select and showing its value but third one is not showing and stay on "please select..." **UNLESS** i'm changing the value of second dropdown to anyother value and then values of third dropdown will appearing.

here is javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
var Floor_id = 'Floor';
var Building_id = 'Building';
var Unit_id = 'Unit';
var initial_Floor_html = '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
var initial_Unit_html = '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
$('#'+Floor_id).html(initial_Floor_html);
$('#'+Unit_id).html(initial_Unit_html);

$('#'+Building_id).change(function(e) {
var selectfvalue = $(this).val();

//Display 'loading' status in the target select list
$('#'+Floor_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

if (selectfvalue == "") {

   $('#'+Floor_id).html(initial_Floor_html);
} else {
  //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
  $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php',
          data:'option=com_parkingreservation&task=getFloorsHTML&fvalue='+selectfvalue,
         success: function(output) {
            //alert(output);
            $('#'+Floor_id).html(output);
        },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
      }});
    }
});

 $('#'+Floor_id).change(function(e) {
var selectuvalue = $(this).val();

//Display 'loading' status in the target select list
$('#'+Unit_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

if (selectuvalue == "") {

   $('#'+Unit_id).html(initial_Unit_html);
} else {
  //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
  $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php',
          data:'option=com_parkingreservation&task=getUnitsHTML&uvalue='+selectuvalue,
         success: function(output) {
            //alert(output);
            $('#'+Unit_id).html(output);
        },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
      }});
    }
});
 });
 });
 </script>
```

and for ajax:

```
}
public function getFloorsHTML() {

     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);
     $myfloors = JRequest::getVar ('fvalue');
     $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'floor_name')));
     $query->from($db->quoteName('#__pk_floors'));
     $query->where($db->quoteName('building')." = ".$db->quote($myfloors));
     $db->setQuery($query);
     $results = $db->loadObjectList();
     foreach ($results as $result) 
     {
       echo '<option value="' . $result->id . '" > ' . $result->floor_name.'</option>'; 
      }
    exit; 
}
public function getUnitsHTML() {

     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);
     $myunits = JRequest::getVar ('uvalue');
     $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'unit_number')));
     $query->from($db->quoteName('#__pk_units'));
     $query->where($db->quoteName('floor')." = ".$db->quote($myunits));
     $db->setQuery($query);
     $results = $db->loadObjectList();
     foreach ($results as $result) 
     {
       echo '<option value="' . $result->id . '" > ' . $result->unit_number.'</option>'; 
      }
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `JRequest` as it's deprecated in Joomla 3.x. You should be using [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput). As for the actual Ajax and trying to populate the 3rd dropdown, are you getting any browser console log errors?

Comment: @Lodder thanks for advise, no i'm not getting any error. the 3rd dropdown is loading only by changing the 2nd dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the issue here. The `.change()` function is not being executed because the content is being change dynamically, therefore you need event delegation.

On your 2nd event, try replacing:

```
$('#'+Floor_id).change(function(e) {
```

with:

```
$(document).on('change', '#'+Floor_id, function(e) {
```

---

## Update 1:

I created a JSFiddle to replicate what you were doing and instead, changed your second event to a function instead, which gets called if the first Ajax request comes back as a success.

Please try replacing **ALL** your code with this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var Floor_id    = $('#Floor');
    var Building_id = $('#Building');
    var Unit_id     = $('#Unit');
    var initial_Floor_html = '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
    var initial_Unit_html  = '<option value="">Please select...</option>';

    Floor_id.html(initial_Floor_html);
    Unit_id.html(initial_Unit_html);

    Building_id.on('change', function(e) {

        var selectvalue = $(this).val();

        //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
        Floor_id.html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

        if (selectvalue == '') 
        {
            Floor_id.html(initial_Floor_html);
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data:'option=com_parkingreservation&task=getFloorsHTML&fvalue='+selectvalue,
                success: function(output) {
                    Floor_id.html(output);
                    updateSelect(Floor_id.val());
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status +  ' ' + thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    Floor_id.on('change', function(e) {
        updateSelect($(this).val());
    });

    function updateSelect(selectvalue) 
    {
        //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
        Unit_id.html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

        if (selectvalue == '') 
        {
            Unit_id.html(initial_Unit_html);
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data:'option=com_parkingreservation&task=getUnitsHTML&uvalue='+selectvalue,
                success: function(output) {
                    Unit_id.html(output);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    }

});
```

I've made some other small improvements along the way too

Comment: replaced but not working.

Comment: Do you have a live preview I can look at?

Comment: @allogos - Ok I'm just creating a JSFiddle and trying to replicate the issue. Will post back in a bit

Comment: @allogos - See update^^^

Comment: Thanks, now 3rd dropdown loading but if you change the value of second dorpdown the 3rd will not change. please test  my link again.

Comment: @allogos - Code updated again. Replace it all. Let me know what happens

Comment: Now the 3rd is not loading at all.

Comment: @allogos - Hmm...try now

Comment: Still same, 3rd is not loading at all.

Comment: @allogos - Updated again.

Comment: Lodder i have one question, i have two form with same three dropdowns one in page A with one continue button and other one in Page B. i can pass dropdown values by continue button from page A to Page B.  url looks like this formid=1&[building][]=value&[floor][]=value. now in case if i use script to call ajax for secnd dropdown, is it possible in script to check if second dropdown doesn't get any value from url then run the script to call ajax?

Comment: Yes, you can simply get the value from the URL then use an `if else` statement, like `if (url !== "") { //do something } else { //do something else }`

Comment: Great. i will try and will get back to you tomorrow. Tnx again.

Comment: Hi Lodder, I tried but not succeed. The scenario is,
pageA) I will select dropdown building (populating from db) and dropdown (Ajax call)
url will pass like: 
index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=8&form[Building][]=1&form[Floor][]=3
PageB) In dropdown Building showing the option with value 1 and dropdown Floor is only showing “please select” and NOT getting the value (which should be 3)
So in script I have to write if statement for floor ONLY, like if the floor getting value from url then show the value else run the script to call ajax for floor. Units in both cases will get value by Ajax call.

Comment: you can try [here](http://blackdeers.net/project/pcp/) from home pass value to reserve. but if you go on reserve page to make new submission then the script is working ok.

Comment: @allogos - I'd suggest asking a [new question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) regarding this, so the conversation section doesn't go on for too long ;)

Comment: ok;) catch me here [link](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/passing-form-value-using-ajax)

Comment: is it possible to have "please select" as default for second and third dopdown after ajax call? right now is showing their very first value.